# Reference for one dimensional dynamics?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for a solid, gentle introduction for an undergraduate student with only a calculus background to one-dimensional dynamical systems with an emphasis on chaotic systems. Something that introduces objects like Markov partitions from a combinatorial point of view but avoids discussion of ergodic theory. I would like to work up to something like Sharkovsky's theorem (e.g. the presentation in the Burns and Hasselblatt proof). The references I have been able to find both move a bit too quickly and are surrounded by/develop more difficult concepts simultaneously.

Comment: Have you seen [this book](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~svanstri/Files/demelo-strien.pdf)? I am not very sure how gentle is it, but as far as I remember it's a pretty solid reference to 1d dynamics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devaney's book: *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems* sounds very well-suited to what you're looking for.